# How are cavalry different from soldiers?

Tags: civ-clicker

Are cavalry stronger or weaker than soldiers? When I send out a raid, it always seems that the cavalry die first, and very quickly. Is there any point in them or should I just send out more soldiers if I can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cavalry deal more damage than soldiers, but take more damage from enemy units. If you are defending and you have 100 or more fortifications, your units will take no damage - this means that, unit for unit, cavalry are more effective.

By contrast, in protracted battles (most raids), the numbers of cavalry will be reduced more quickly meaning that they deal less damage overall (despite their damage bonus), making them less effective.

There is one other very minor advantage to cavalry: they do not require metal to build, making them easier to create in certain situations.

Comment: And you don't get much more authoritative than that. ;-)